# Leafpad - remove document name and page number from printed page

Tags: printing, gtk, editors, lxde

I am using `leafpad` text editor on Debian (version 0.8.18.1)

When I print text from `leafpad`, the document name and the page numbers are automatically printed on the page.

i am not sure if these settings come from `leafpad` itself, or from some system print settings (I am using LXDE desktop environment).

Is it possible to hide document name and the page numbers on the printed page?

I would be happy to recompile leafpad from source, if somebody could point me to the section in source code that needs to be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code has this builtin. You can see the code in file [src/gtkprint.c](https://github.com/Distrotech/leafpad/blob/master/src/gtkprint.c#L82)
in the function `cb_draw_page()`:

```
pango_layout_set_text(layout_lh, page_title, -1);
...
pango_cairo_show_layout(cr, layout_lh);
...
page_text = g_strdup_printf("%d / %d", page_nr + 1, n_pages);
layout_rh = gtk_print_context_create_pango_layout(ctx);
...
pango_cairo_show_layout(cr, layout_rh);
```

Comment out at least the two `pango_cairo_show_layout()` calls shown here.